# Getting contract address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I saw an example about this, while was searching it on the internet.

I want to deploy a new contract which is ProjectContract. However, I could not get contract address as below. I think this is for old version.

```
address newProjectAddress = new ProjectContract(name, description, requiredPrice, msg.sender);
```

And the error message is:
[image: This the error message]

How can I do that for the new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, the you cant convert a contract to address **implicitly**.
You can, however, convert the them **explicitly**.

```
address newProjectAddress = address(new ProjectContract(...));
```

The type returned by `new ProjectContract(...)` is `ProjectContract` and not `address`.